# Flutter update Text data in real time

Tags: flutter, widget, real-time

I am very new to Flutter and I'm stuck for an answer.

I want to make a very simple time picker style object without the need for a popover or other interference. So, therefore.....

I have a `String` object and a `Text` widget to display that `String`. The `Text` widget has a vertical drag gesture recognizer around it. When I drag, I use some calculations to adjust the String's value, with the expectation that this will be shown via the `Text` widget. This works, except for one major problem.

The `Text` widget can take 30 seconds or more to change, therefore it is impossible for the user to see the value they are selecting using the drag method.

Is there any way for force the `Text` widget to display the String when it is changed?

I have tried wrapping just the `Text` widget within the gesture recognizer, however the touch area is then too small, hence the other Text and the Padding widgets.

```
child: Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20,10, 20, 5),
  child: Column(
    children:<Widget>[
      Text("Start of Day",
        style: new TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontSize: 16.0,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
      Text(_startOfDay,
        style: new TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontSize: 16.0,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
onVerticalDragStart: (DragStartDetails details){
  _offset = 0;
},
onVerticalDragUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails moveDetails){
  _offset = _offset + moveDetails.delta.dy;
  if(_offset > 10||_offset < -10){
    var startparts = _startOfDay.split(":");
    double startHour = double.parse(startparts[0]);
    double startMinute = (double.parse(startparts[1]))/15;
    if(_offset > 10){
      startMinute = startMinute - 1;
      if(startMinute < 0){
        startMinute = 3;
        startHour = startHour - 1;
      }
      if(startHour < 0){
        startHour=0;
        startMinute=0;
      }
      _startOfDay = startHour.toInt().toString().padLeft(2,'0')+ ':' + (startMinute * 15).toInt().toString().padLeft(2,'0');
      _offset = _offset - 10;
      globals.startOfDay=_startOfDay;
    }
    if(_offset < -10){
      startMinute = startMinute + 1;
      if(startMinute > 3){
        startMinute = 0;
        startHour = startHour + 1;
      }
      if(startHour == 24){
        startHour=23;
        startMinute=3;
      }
      _startOfDay = startHour.toInt().toString().padLeft(2,'0')+ ':' + (startMinute * 15).toInt().toString().padLeft(2,'0');
      globals.startOfDay=_startOfDay;
      _offset = _offset + 10;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're missing is the `setState(...)`.

When your property changes you need to call `setState()` to rebuild your widget with the new state of your properties. In this case, you need to call `setState` whenever the `_startOfDay` changes.

Try this code:

```
child: Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20,10, 20, 5),
  child: Column(
    children:<Widget>[
      Text("Start of Day",
        style: new TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontSize: 16.0,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
      Text(_startOfDay,
        style: new TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontSize: 16.0,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
onVerticalDragStart: (DragStartDetails details){
  _offset = 0;
},
onVerticalDragUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails moveDetails){
  _offset = _offset + moveDetails.delta.dy;
  if(_offset > 10||_offset < -10){
    var startparts = _startOfDay.split(":");
    double startHour = double.parse(startparts[0]);
    double startMinute = (double.parse(startparts[1]))/15;
    if(_offset > 10){
      startMinute = startMinute - 1;
      if(startMinute < 0){
        startMinute = 3;
        startHour = startHour - 1;
      }
      if(startHour < 0){
        startHour=0;
        startMinute=0;
      }
      _startOfDay = startHour.toInt().toString().padLeft(2,'0')+ ':' + (startMinute * 15).toInt().toString().padLeft(2,'0');
      setState(() {});
      _offset = _offset - 10;
      globals.startOfDay=_startOfDay;
    }
    if(_offset < -10){
      startMinute = startMinute + 1;
      if(startMinute > 3){
        startMinute = 0;
        startHour = startHour + 1;
      }
      if(startHour == 24){
        startHour=23;
        startMinute=3;
      }
      _startOfDay = startHour.toInt().toString().padLeft(2,'0')+ ':' + (startMinute * 15).toInt().toString().padLeft(2,'0');
      globals.startOfDay=_startOfDay;
      _offset = _offset + 10;
      setState(() {});
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! Sorry I could not find that in the documentation.